# Spring Ldaptemplate 2 add member to group

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

what is best way to add member in group using spring LdapTemplate.
I have successfully create user and remove user ex.
But I'm trying to add member then I'm facing issue.

Add Member Code:

```
public boolean addMemberToGroup(List<String> groupList, User user) {
    boolean isAddedSuccessfully=false;
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<groupList.size();i++){
            Name groupDn = buildGroupDn(groupList.get(i));
            DirContextOperations ctx =   ldapTemplate.lookupContext(groupDn);
            ctx.addAttributeValue("member",buildPersonDn(user.getUid()));
            ldapTemplate.update(ctx);
            }
        isAddedSuccessfully=true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        isAddedSuccessfully=false;

    }
    return isAddedSuccessfully;
}

private Name buildGroupDn(String groupName) {
    return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("cn=groups").add("cn", groupName).build();
}

private Name buildPersonDn(String userID) {
    return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance()
        .add("uid", userID).add("cn", "users")
        .build();
```

}

> Exception Of addMemberToGroup: Class class org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter must have a class level interface org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry annotation.

please let me know what i am missing.

Answer (score 2):

The `update`method is intended for use with [ODM](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/#odm) annotated classes. When working with `DirContextAdapter` you should use the [modifyAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapOperations.html#modifyAttributes(org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations)) method.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, it's one I had too recently. For anyone coming here in the future, this question is similar to the one found at [Spring Malformed 'member' attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363080/spring-malformed-member-attribute-value). Putting together info from both questions, I found the solution to my problem, and share here what worked for me.

In addition to using the `modifyAttributes` method of the `LdapTemplate` class, it's also important to pass a `String` object as the second parameter of the `addAttributeValue` method of the `DirContextOperations` class when adding a member, rather than passing a `Name` object. The `toString` method called on the corresponding `Name` object does the trick.

Original code:

```
DirContextOperations ctx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(groupDn);
ctx.addAttributeValue("member",buildPersonDn(user.getUid()));
ldapTemplate.update(ctx);
```

Try this instead:

```
DirContextOperations ctx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(groupDn);
ctx.addAttributeValue("member",buildPersonDn(user.getUid()).toString());
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(ctx);
```