# Spring Malformed 'member' attribute value

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I m creating an application that has to connect to an active directory.

I m actually facing a problem when dealing with updating a group member.

The group name is : **GG-Collaboration-AgenceXXX**

Here's my `GroupRepository` class code that throws the exception :

```
 public void addMemberToGroup(String groupName, User user) {
        Name groupDn = this.buildGroupDn(groupName);
        Name userDn = this.buildPersonDn(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName(), user.getCompany(), user.getCountry().toString());
        DirContextOperations ctx = this.ldapTemplate.lookupContext(groupDn);
        ctx.addAttributeValue("member", userDn);
        System.out.println(userDn);
        this.ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(ctx);
    }

 private Name buildGroupDn(String groupName) {
        return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=" + groupName).build();
    }

    private Name buildPersonDn(String fullname, String company, String country) {
        return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("DC=test,DC=lan").add("OU", "Utilisateurs").add("CN", fullname).build();
    }
```

Here's my fullstack error :

```
Malformed 'member' attribute value; nested exception is javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: Malformed 'member' attribute value; remaining name 'CN=GG-Collaboration-AgenceXXX'
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:132)
Caused by: javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: Malformed 'member' attribute value
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.encodeAttribute(LdapClient.java:984)
```

Answer (score 8):

The "member" attribute only allows strings as value and not `LDAPName` objects. So convert your `userDn` to a string before putting it into the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value you are getting in "member" attribute? There are some special characters which are not allowed. 
[Allowed LDAP Attribute Characters](http://followmesupport.ringdale.com/Knowledgebase/Allowed-LDAP-attribute-characters)

Answer (score 0):

When adding attribute value, just call `toString()` method on `javax.naming.Name` types. Like this:

```
ctx.addAttributeValue("member", userDn.toString());
```

It will solve this issue.